# How can a program started by udev call socket()?

Tags: sockets, linux-device-driver, udev

The program (u50/u60 USB device driver daemon) succeeds from the shell but fails if started upon boot by udev.

I tried to use sd_listen_fds() but it returned 0.

```
    int lonsd; // file descriptor for the new socket
    struct ifreq ifr = {0};
    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    int found = 0;
    int fd;
    int num_fds; // number of file descriptors
    // https://insujang.github.io/2018-11-27/udev-device-manager-for-the-linux-kernel-in-userspace/
    // Currently, udev is a part of systemd, therefore it uses systemd’s socket protocol.

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s devstr:%s, ldisc:%d\n", __func__, devstr, ldisc);

    lonsd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP));
    if (lonsd < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s socket() failed - must be udev\n", __func__);

        lonsd = -EBADF;
        //systemd/src/udev/udevd.c:
        //static int listen_fds(int* ret_ctrl, int* ret_netlink) {
        num_fds = sd_listen_fds(true);
        if (num_fds < 0) {
            syslog(LOG_CRIT, "%s sd_listen_fds() failed\n", __func__);
        }
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s num_fds:%d\n", __func__, num_fds);
        for (fd = SD_LISTEN_FDS_START; fd < num_fds + SD_LISTEN_FDS_START; fd++) {
            if (sd_is_socket(fd, AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP)) > 0) {
                if (lonsd >= 0) {
                    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "%s EINVAL: lonsd >= 0\n", __func__);
                    return -EINVAL;
                }
                lonsd = fd;
            }
        }
    }
    else syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s lonsd:%d\n", __func__, lonsd);
```

I am porting a driver for a LonWorks USB interface (Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0920:5550 Echelon Co. Echelon U60 FT Network Interface). The u50.ko driver was inserted. When run from the shell, "lonifd" creates a network device.

> 5: lon10: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state
> UNKNOWN group default qlen 10 link/[2384] inet 44.1.110.125/24 brd
> 44.1.110.255 scope global lon10 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever –

But when started by udev, socket() fails.

Comment: What is a "u50/u60 USB device driver daemon"?

Comment: I added info to my question.

Comment: Is it run with the same command line arguments when run from the shell and when started by udev?

Comment: Do you know the `errno` value when `socket()` fails?

Comment: Is the kernel's "af_packet" driver compiled as a module or built-in? If it is a compiled as a module, is it already loaded when udev runs the daemon? If not, you could maybe configure udev to load the "af_packet" module.

Comment: When started by udev, the args are "-d /dev/ttyACM0."  I have tried it with no args.  It  succeeds from the shell with or without args.  The error number is 22 -  "Invalid argument." How can I check the af_packet module? "lsmod" does not list af_packet. I just tried ETH_P_ALL instead of ETH_P_IP - same.

Comment: modinfo u50
filename:       /lib/modules/5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64/kernel/drivers/lon/u50.ko
description:    U50 SMIP Driver 1.4 L2
alias:          tty-ldisc-28
license:        GPL
rhelversion:    9.3
srcversion:     362804F98F43B1D74EDFADE
depends:
retpoline:      Y
name:           u50
vermagic:       5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions

Comment: modinfo af_packet
name:           af_packet
filename:       (builtin)
alias:          net-pf-17
license:        GPL
file:           net/packet/af_packet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257026/discussion-between-william-dickerson-and-ian-abbott).

Comment: udev may detect the device before networking is started.

Comment: I had tried sleep. It also fails if I unplug/plug in the USB.

Comment: The README calls it a daemon.  I found some discussion about starting a long running program from udev.  I couldn't get "at now" to work but I'll try starting a systemd service Monday.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1364509/127177

Comment: Thanks.  It is working and I will post my answer.  I couldn't determine the proper sys-subsystem-net-devices-usb0.device in that answer (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6/4-1.6:1.0/tty/ttyACM0).  So I modified the rule since it was already starting the program.  Now it runs "lonifd" when the device is plugged in and stops it when it is unplugged.  I postponed handling arguments since it is very unlikely we will have more than one on a system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, I changed the rule to start a service. Now it runs "lonifd" upon boot if the device is found, and when the device is plugged in and stops it when it is unplugged.

The revised rule: /etc/udev/rules.d/90-liftd.rules.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0920", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5550", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="u60.service"
```

/etc/systemd/system/u60.service

```
[Unit]
Description=U60 USB Lontalk Interface
Documentation=

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lonifd
Type=exec
Restart=on-failure
```